# Update Parent Record with value from Latest Child Record

Tags: apex, trigger, bulkification

I have a trigger that updates a parent record with value from latest child record entered but I'm having trouble bulkifying it. Here's what I've got:

```
//Parent Object - ObjectA
//Child Object - ObjectB


if( trigger.isinsert ){

        List<Id> Object_A_IDs = new List<id>();

            for(ObjectB__c t : trigger.new){
                Object_A_IDs.add(t.ObjectAID__c); //ObjectAID__c is the master detail relationship
            }

        List<ObjectA> List_of_ObjectA = [SELECT Id, To_update_Field_1__c, To_update_Field_1__c FROM Contact WHERE id in: Object_A_IDs];             

        List<ObjectB> List_of_ObjectB = [SELECT Id, source_field_1__c, source_field_2__c FROM ObjectB__c
                                                   WHERE ObjectAID__c in: List_of_ObjectA ORDER BY  createdate DESC LIMIT 1 ]; 

        If(List_of_ObjectB.size() != 0)
        {
            for(ObjectA a : List_of_ObjectA){
                a.To_update_Field_1__c = List_of_ObjectB[0].source_field_1__c;
                a.To_update_Field_2__c = List_of_ObjectB[0].source_field_2__c;
            }

                update List_of_ObjectA;  
             }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Parent Object - ObjectA
//Child Object - ObjectB

if( trigger.isinsert ){
    Set<Id> Object_A_IDs = new Set<id>();
    List<ObjectA__c> objaList = new List<ObjectA__c>();
    for(ObjectB__c t : trigger.new){
        Object_A_IDs.add(t.ObjectAID__c); //ObjectAID__c is the master detail relationship
    }
    for(ObjectA__c obja: [select id,(select id,name from ObjectBs__r ORDER BY  createdate DESC LIMIT 1) from ObjectA__c where id IN:Object_A_IDs]){
        if(!obja.ObjectBs__r.isEmpty()){
            obja.name = obja.ObjectBs__r[0].name;
            objaList.add(obja);
        }
    }
    if(!objaList.isEmpty()){
        update objaList;
    }
 }
```